# Invalid CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX; GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx (kernel32)

Tags: c#, .net-core, pinvoke

## GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx invalid return value

I am trying to change the console's color palette. To get this done I first need to `Get` my `ConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` and then `Set` it. The problem is that I can't even get a valid `ConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` from the `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE`.
The code below throws this error message:
***System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'***
The handle is valid and yet I get this error. I have quadruple-checked every data type and related pinvoke entry - everything is looking good to me. There is no *sample code* for `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` and I haven't been able to find a working solution yet.
**My sources:**

- [pinvoke: ConsoleFunctions (kernel32)](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ConsoleFunctions.html)
- [msdocs: CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffer-infoex)
- [msdocs: COLORREF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/colorref)

**Example App (.NET Core 3.1):**
For this code to work, the project's build properties must allow unsafe code.
[Properties -> Build -> Allow unsafe code]

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ScreenBufferInfoExample
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern SafeFileHandle GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern unsafe bool GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(SafeFileHandle hConsoleOutput,
                                                                      out CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX ConsoleScreenBufferInfo);

        static void Main()
        {
            SafeFileHandle stdOut = GetStdHandle(-11);
            if(stdOut.IsInvalid)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
            CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX info = new CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX();
            info.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(info);
            if(!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(stdOut, out info)) {
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());// <- this gets thrown
                // System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public COORD dwSize;
        public COORD dwCursorPosition;
        public ushort wAttributes;
        public SMALL_RECT srWindow;
        public COORD dwMaximumWindowSize;

        public ushort wPopupAttributes;
        public bool bFullscreenSupported;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
        public COLORREF[] ColorTable;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct COORD
    {
        public short X;
        public short Y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct SMALL_RECT
    {
        public short Left;
        public short Top;
        public short Right;
        public short Bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct COLORREF
    {
        public uint ColorDWORD;

        public COLORREF(int r, int g, int b)
            : this(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)) { }
        public COLORREF(Color color)
        {
            ColorDWORD = (uint)color.R
                         + (((uint)color.G) << 8)
                         + (((uint)color.B) << 16);
        }

        public Color GetColor()
        {
            return Color.FromArgb((int)(0x000000FFU & ColorDWORD),
                                  (int)(0x0000FF00U & ColorDWORD) >> 8,
                                  (int)(0x00FF0000U & ColorDWORD) >> 16);
        }

        public void SetColor(Color color)
        {
            ColorDWORD = (uint)color.R
                         + (((uint)color.G) << 8)
                         + (((uint)color.B) << 16);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI. *"For this script to work,"* - this is not a script

Comment: I didn't just throw code at you. I posted an executable sample, included related source material, and indicated my problem as well as my goal. I also tried numerous solutions that I found on this page. None of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pinvoke.net is often useful, but not always right.

As you need to pass information in and out of the GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx method, the parameter cannot be `out`, but needs to be `ref`.

So the correct declaration would be

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern unsafe bool GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(SafeFileHandle hConsoleOutput, 
    ref CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX ConsoleScreenBufferInfo);
```

called as `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(stdOut, ref info)`.

(I just corrected the page on pinvoke.net accordingly)

Comment: Thank you VERY much! I've already noticed multiple missing signatures, but didn't expect an actual error on pinvoke. Every other solution published on stackoverflow took a working GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx for granted, and so did I. You should check on older related questions as well, I bet you can help a lot of people with this knowledge. Like I said: I didn't find a working solution.